# Why can not I close tab (even window) with validated with error Devexpress control?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, user-interface, devexpress

I use devexpress wpf user control ([SpinEdit](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfEditorsSpinEdittopic)). 
When I enter the wrong value ( greater than max value) the error is shown within control.
At this moment I cant close the tab with this control and even whole wpf window. I cannot switch the tab. When the value within the range (no errors) I can do these actions.

Tell me please why and how can I override this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The described behavior is correct - wrong values should not be posted in editor by default and the entire application should wait until a correct value is entered. Anyway, you can override this behavior using the [BaseEdit.InvalidValueBehavior](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsBaseEdit_InvalidValueBehaviortopic) property (use the `InvalidValueBehavior.AllowLeaveEditor` value).

Answer (score 2):

I think the whole purpose of the validation is making the errors in data impossible when the data is entered manually. If nobody will answer on how to override this behavior you could always write a support ticket.